# Как сделать многоразовые покупки в Google play Developer console

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-purchases

Здравствуйте, не могу найти решение  проблемы ,связанное с внутриигровыми покупками в Гугле. Дело в том, что я хочу сделать  их(покупки)  многоразовыми, но посетив настройки контента я увидел такую картину( скрин)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В первом случае покупка будет всего один раз, во втором же ,подписка. Покопавшись в ютубе, я видел ,что в выборе типа продукта была вкладка "Не контролируется Google", но у меня, как видите, этой вкладки нет. Объясните пожалуйста, решить данную проблему.

Answer (score 1):

После того, как был куплен какой-то продукт, то его можно использовать (потребить). Для этого в **In-app Billing Version 3 API** предусмотрен `Consume`. Подробнее об использовании (потреблении) купленных продуктов: [тут](https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#consume).

После того, как продукт будет использован (потреблен), то он исчезнет из списка купленных продуктов у пользователя.

В консоли разработчика не надо указывать, что какая-то покупка может быть многоразовой. Использование купленных продуктов происходит **в приложении**.

У гугла есть урок о том, как производить покупки и использовать их: [In-app Billing Tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/preparing-iab-app.html#GetSample), в разделе **Purchasing Products** есть подраздел с описанием, как использовать (потреблять) купленные продукты: [Consume a purchase](https://developer.android.com/training/in-app-billing/purchase-iab-products.html#Consume).